# Баг с Roboto шрифтом на десктопном хроме

Tags: css, google-chrome, шрифты

(оригинальный вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512815/bug-with-roboto-font-and-break-word-on-desktop-chrome)

Баг обнаружен на десктопных версиях:

1. beta Chrome version 51
2. Chrome 53 (canary)

Дело в странном поведении строки при сочетании букв нижнего регистра `rt`.

Автоматически происходит перевод строки как на рисунке ниже -

[image: strange Roboto font behaviour]

Вот пример кода демонстрирующий баг:

```css
.container {
  word-break: break-word;
}
.line {
  padding: 5px;
}
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">rt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">rt rt rt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">morty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo rty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo Rty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo rTy</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Бага нету в хроме для планшета и смартфона.

Как убрать баг используя данные стили `css` ?

P. S. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему такой баг собственно имеет место быть?

Comment: Кросс-языковые ссылки должны быть в обоих вопросах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё-таки нашёл решение:

```
font-kerning: none;
```

Хотя ещё вопрос, насколько оно приемлемо...

```css
.container {
  word-break: break-word;
}
.line {
  padding: 5px;
}
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-kerning: none;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">rt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">rt rt rt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">morty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo rty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo Rty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo rTy</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот несколько костылей (нормальных способов не нашёл):

- Закрыть `div` в начале следующей строки
  Код выглядит ужасно, зато без последствий для пользователя
- Перед закрытием `</div>` поставить пробел
  В таком случае изменяется отступ справа и пользователь это увидит

А проблемы с первым `rt` в моём хроме не наблюдается.

```css
.container {
  word-break: break-word;
}
.line {
  padding: 5px;
}
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">rt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">rt rt rt
</div> <!-- Закрыть элемент в начале следующей строки -->
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">morty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo rty </div> <!-- Добавить пробел => поменялся отступ справа -->
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo Rty</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="inline-block">mo rTy</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересно, но только с первым `rt` у меня все еще проблемы при таком подходе)

Comment: @Lepta, у меня с ним вообще проблемы нет, даже в исходном варианте. Chrome 50.0.2661.102 (Официальная сборка) m (64 бит), Windows 7.